# parLapply on 2 set of list

Tags: r, parallel-processing

im trying to run a function over 2 set of data
each data are set of Latitude and Longitude, example :

```
a <- data.frame(Location = c("a","b"), Latitude = c(99.1,99.2), Longitude = c(114.1,114.2))
b <- data.frame(Location = c("c","d"), Latitude = c(99.3,99.4), Longitude = c(114.3,114.4))
```

the function are (just example, using a pythagoras)

```
fn_dist <- function(xi,yi){dist <- sqrt((a[xi,2] - b[yi,2]) ^ 2 + (a[xi,3] - b[yi,3]) ^ 2)}
```

currently im using below :

```
CenterCount <- nrow(a) #find Center Count
DestinationCount <- nrow(b) #find Destination Count
CalcList <- seq(1, (CenterCount * DestinationCount))
```

setup parallel

```
UseCore <- 28
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", UseCore))
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(SPEI))
clusterExport(cl, ls())
```

run the list

```
ResultList <- parLapply(cl, CalcList, fn_Dist)
```

bind the result

```
Result <- rbind.fill(ResultList)
```

stop cluster

```
stopCluster(cl)
```

so in short, what im currently doing is create a list for each combination, infer the value of ci and di based on i (list index) using

```
ci <- floor((x - 1) / DestinationCount) + 1
di <- x - ((ci - 1) * DestinationCount)
```

and calculate accordingly

The problem :
the list CalcList tookup quite big RAM after certain number.

For now, i'm quite satisfied with the performance of parLapply, only have problem with CalcList took up RAM

I have also tried doFuture and parallel with foreach %dopar% instead of parLapply, so far parLapply are the fastest one

How can i avoid creating CalcList to feed calculation list into parLapply?

Comment: You have several typos as well, such as defining your function as `fn_dist` then calling it as `fn_Dist`. Won't change as I don't know if this breaks anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to calculate the (potentially large) `CalcList`. You can use either the list of centres or the list of destinations in the `parLapply`. The function you are calling would then apply your original function on each element of the other list, e.g. using `lapply`.

Comment: Ah you are right. I was thinking to "truly" parallelize the function i need to list all the list and let parLapply to take care of it. Since the Center list is already bigger than core count, i should be able to parallelize in that lebel.